# How to take elements of a Matrix and use each one as Input-Variable for the same function?

Tags: matlab, function, element

I have given a matrix with `485x1` elements. MatLab shall take the first 12 of them and make them a new matrix.

Then I have a variable named `C` and a function `f(C)`. 
MatLab shall take the first element of the new matrix and make it `C`. Then it shall perform `f(C)` and save the result as `result1`.
Then it should take the second element of the new matrix and make it `C`. Then it shall perform `f(C)` again and save the result as `result2` and so on.
So in the end I need 12 result variables.

How can I program this?

Comment: Look up `mat2cell` and `cellfun`.

Comment: Try reading something about matrix indexing http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html and for loops: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/for.html

Comment: Please post some code attempts or show what you have tried. Have you tried searching google.com or using the search feature for other similar questions?

Answer (score 0):

This is question asks for very basic stuff. Like adressing the first 12 elements of a matrix. You might want to consider reading a few FAQs.
However a basic solution can look like this:

```
M = [1:485]'; %// a 485x1 matrix (vector)
newMatrix = M(1:12); %// newMatrix contains the first 12 elements of M (also vector)
result = cell(1,12); %// result as a cell
f = @(x) x+1; % a function f
for i = 1:12
    C = newMatrix(i); % get each value from newMatrix, call it C
    result{i} = f(C); % apply f() on c and store the result
end
```

It is not a good idea to generate variables `result1`, `result2`, ..., `result12`, you can read more about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143-how-do-i-make-a-series-of-variables-a1-a2-a3-a10). Better use a cell for storing the variables, you can then adress the i-th result as `result{i}`.